# Can we do a bulk Update without specifying a document ID for Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Can we do  a bulk update in Elastic Search  without specifying document ID . Iam not able to bulk update without documentId, Is there is any way for bulk update by queryby method

```
length = len(test_final)
steps = 100
for i in range(0, length, steps):
    end_index = length-1 if i+steps>length else i+steps
    temp_list = test_final[i: end_index]
    bulk_file = ''
    actions = [{
        "_op_type": "update",
        "_index": "test_detail",
        "_type": "test_datas",
        "upsert": {
            {source['dataId']:{
                "test_value": int(test_data ['test_value'])
            }}
        },
        "script":{  "query": {
    "term": {
      "test_Id": test_data ['dataId']
    }

        }}}
        for test_data in temp_list
    ]
    helpers.bulk(es, actions)
```

Comment: So, you don't know the ID of the document you're willing to update, is that correct?

Comment: yes , can  we update using another field  which is unique

Comment: The [update by query endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) can help, but it's not compatible with the bulk endpoint, i.e. you cannot send several update-by-query in one bulk

Comment: is there is any other way bulk-update update-by-query method.

Comment: How many updates are we talking? how frequently?

Comment: 1 lakh updates  in minimum 10 minutes

Comment: The bulk endpoint just won't help you here but you can definitely issue a serie of update by query updates and track them one by one.

Comment: @NithishAlbin have to resolve this issue without _id....?